# Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid operation (1282) - LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I tried to use lwjgl to create a game. I did something wrong and got error below. How I can fix it? What it actually means?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid operation (1282)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Util.checkGLError(Util.java:59)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.java:338)
at com.base.engine.Shader.setUniformf(Shader.java:119)
at com.base.engine.Game.update(Game.java:63)
at com.base.engine.MainComponent.run(MainComponent.java:85)
at com.base.engine.MainComponent.start(MainComponent.java:38)
at com.base.engine.MainComponent.main(MainComponent.java:131)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please post sample code following these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My code is here: http://paste.ofcode.org/6SQje6QFxczhY2FYwekUcD
and here:  http://paste.ofcode.org/JtdfSU8CyGh5QsKkdc9qRH

Comment: Please add the RELEVANT code to the question. Of-site links are not welcome on SO.

Comment: Yes, please embed the relevant sample code in the question itself.

Comment: I don't know how! :(

Comment: Just copy the lines around 119 from Shader.java and lines around 63 from Game.java (since this is where the error happens) and paste it into your question. If there are variables used in this line, make a breakpoint on it, note the values and also add them to your question.

Comment: Thank you BDL, now there is codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [OpenGL 3.3 Reference Pages](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/):

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if there is no current program object.

You bind your shader program in the `render()` method of `Game`:

```
public void render()
{
    shader.bind();
    mesh.draw();
}
```

However, as seen in the [`MainComponent`](https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameEngine/blob/d8778e00209978515176217952dc615997c7e0a0/src/com/base/engine/MainComponent.java) class from Tutorial 11:

```
private void run()
{
    // ...
        while(unprocessedTime > frameTime)
        {
            // ...
            game.update();
            // ...
        }
        if(render)
        {
            render();
            frames++;
        }
        // ...
}

private void render()
{
    RenderUtil.clearScreen();
    game.render();
    Window.render();
}
```

Here `game.update()` gets called before `render()` (and therefore `game.render()`).

Because the shader program is only bound in `game.render()`, at the first call of `game.update()` there is no program bound, which means `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is thrown.

This isn't really an issue because from the second frame on the program is bound and so all will be working perfectly from there. However, you probably have debug mode switched on, which means LWJGL won't silently ignore OpenGL errors, instead throwing exceptions.

So you can either switch debug mode off or, what I would recommend, bind your shader program once at the end of the `Game` constructor instead of every frame. As long as you only have one shader program, it will work perfectly.