# Fragment shader won't compile

Tags: java, opengl, compilation, glsl, lwjgl

I'm trying to get the shaders from this tutorial to work:
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/discard.php

I copied the source code into two files, but neither will compile.

This is the code I have:

```
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    vertexShader  = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    StringBuilder vertexShaderSource   = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder fragmentShaderSource = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/shader.vert"));
        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();

        while(line != null){
            line = reader.readLine();

            if(line != null){
                vertexShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        }
        reader.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Vertex no load.");
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/shader.frag"));
        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();

        while(line != null){
            line = reader.readLine();

            if(line != null){
                fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        }
        reader.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Frag no load.");
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println(fragmentShaderSource);


    glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    if(glGetShader(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE){
        System.err.println("Vertex no compile");
    }
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    if(glGetShader(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE){
        System.err.println("frag no compile");
    }


    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glValidateProgram(shaderProgram);
```

I've had shaders work before, so its not the setup (that I know of) but when I copied and pasted neither file would compile anymore.

Is my setup wrong somehow?

EDIT >>>

I can't seem to import glGetShaderiv

I am using LWJGL and imported everything from there. Could I be missing a JAR file?

EDIT >>>

Related Question:

[I get error "Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid operation (1282)", what it is?, how I can fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993104/i-get-error-exception-in-thread-main-org-lwjgl-opengl-openglexception-invali)

Comment: Try printing out the compiler error with [glGetShaderInfoLog](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Shader_error_handling)

Comment: Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Eclipse isn't recognizing that statement.

Comment: What openGL version are you using? Are you using core profile? The shaders you posted are old OpenGL (< 3.3) and if you are using core pofile >= 3.3 then you cant use variables like `gl_MultiTexCoord0`. Maybe this causes the error

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) -->  4.2.0

Comment: Is this an up to date version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the source files incorrectly.

```
line = reader.readLine();

while(line != null){
    line = reader.readLine();

    if(line != null){
        fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
    }
}
```

Here, you first read the first line of the file. If it isn't null, you continue reading lines and appending them to the buffer. However, you don't actually append the line after the `readLine()` statement outside of the loop, which means it is discarded and the shader compiler gets a source file with the first line missing. Therefore it doesn't know about `varying vec2 vTexCoord;` or `sampler2D myTexture;`, raising compiler errors when they are used later in the code.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. ```
   line = reader.readLine();
   if (line != null) {
       fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
   }

   while (line != null) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. ```
   while (true) {
       line = reader.readLine();

       if (line == null) {
           break;
       }

       fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
   }
   ```
3. ```
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
   }
   ```

Which one to use depends on your preferences. 1 contains redundant code, which is almost never the best solution. 2 is a commonly used way of reading arbitrary files; and while 3 is shorter, some people don't like assigning variables in loop control statements.

Comment: I implemented the break logic. I think that fixed the vertex shader, but the fragment shader still won't compile. I'm guessing that the 'myTexture' isn't specified (it's not) but that still doesn't explain why eclipse won't recognize glGetShaderiv. I can't import that for some reason.

Comment: I'm also guessing vTexCoord isn't specified either, where I should fill in the vertex of texture. Can the shader grab a vector I defined in my java source? Same with texture, can I just specify an existing texture without any imports or whatnot? How does the shader source know what vector/texture I'm referring to?

Comment: Which LWJGL version are you using? LWJGL3 changed some methods so they now include the v on the end, but in version 2 you have to use [`glGetShaderi`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL20.html#glGetShaderi%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: glGetShaderi isn't recognized either. I must be missing a JAR.

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) --> 4.2.0

Comment: This is the OpenGL version. Try printing `org.lwjgl.Sys.getVersion()`.

Comment: Your other OpenGL functions do work though, I suppose? glGetShaderi is in the same package as those, so maybe you didn't use the correct parameters. With autocompletion enabled, try typing `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glGetShaderi`and see whether Eclipse can find it.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. And the version returned as 2.9.1

Comment: This glGetShaderInfoLog stuff seems complex, especially with an older version of glGetShaderiv; the older documentation is pretty sparse. Do you think its worth updating?

Comment: I would definitely update to 2.9.3, but LWJGL3 is completely different and would require much relearning. And to print the shader log you can use `System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));`. Be sure to do the same with the program info log after linking.